# How to display Chinese characters in an MFC dialog

Tags: c++, unicode, mfc, cjk

I need to display Chinese characters in an MFC dialog.

NOTE: The string contains multibyte-characters.

I am using it as shown below. Is this correct?

```
SetWindowTextW(pChatUtils->m_hWnd, L"測試");
```

Comment: I don't know much about MFC, but I guess it would be helpful if you could show the code you currently use (reduced to a minimal example). Also, make sure you search for duplicate questions.

Comment: Two ways. Set your locale for whichever flavour of Chinese you are using, Or, use the wide string methods. Your usage above is correct, but your string is not multibyte.

Comment: From the paste its not clear if your using UTF8 chars or Unicode chars. Might be better to use this kind of notation L"\xFFDF ... that way you dont need to worry you used the right encoding in your cpp file.

Comment: Yes it should show the Chinese text if your system local is set to Chinese correctly.